# Custom animate navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-animation, navigation-drawer

I have implemented Google's navigation drawer and I would like to add a custom animation when I click a menu item.

Ideally the menu would slide back as if closing, leaving a small sliver of the menu open. A dialog would open with an animation, originating from the space beside the selected menu item.
Something like this..

[image]

I tried to animate the left_drawer element on the x axis using ObjectAnimator, but this displaces the whole screen.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it so the drawer is only peaking, try using `drawerLayout.closeDrawers(true)`.

According to the source though, this closes all drawers (if you have more then one).

[DrawLayout source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java)